# Brotli in a React application using server side rendering(SSR)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, brotli

I'm currently wiring up an application with SSR in react.  However, I'm 
having issues with the server NOT returning responses in a Brotli 
compressed file format.  I do see that my br files are getting generated 
by webpack in my client webpack config file.  But my server does not 
pick up on returning br files back to my client. FYI....I also have my 
webpack for the client generate gz files as well. The files I'm trying to return back in br mode is the client_bundle.js file and app.css.

As you will see in my server.js file I send back a 
response in an HTML string format.  I have tried changing my link and 
script tags to return app.css.br and client_bundle.js.br but no avail.

Do you know what I may be doing wrong and why my server won't return 
and/or client will not pickup the br files for CSS and JS?

FYI....I'm using nodejs, express-static-zip in my server.js file.  In 
addition, I'm using compression-webpack-plugin and brotli-webpack-plugin 
to generate the br and gz files for app.css and client_bundle.js.  Another 
side note, I'm building my client files into build/public and my server 
files into build.

Thanks for any assistance.

webpack.client.js

```js
const path = require("path");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const BrotliPlugin = require("brotli-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode:"development",
  optimization: {
    usedExports: true
  },
  entry: "./src/client/client.js",
  output: {
    filename: "client_bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build/public/"),
    publicPath: "/build/public/"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: "/node_modules"
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: ["css-loader", "postcss-loader", "sass-loader"]
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: "app.css"
    }),
      new CompressionPlugin({
          filename: '[path].gz[query]'
      }),
      new BrotliPlugin({
          asset: '[path].br[query]',
          test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/,
          threshold: 10240,
          minRatio: 0.8
      })
  ]
};
```

Server.js

```js
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import React from "react";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { StaticRouter, matchPath } from "react-router-dom";
import serialize from "serialize-javascript";
import routes from "../shared/routes";
import configureStore from "../shared/configureStore";
import App from "../shared/app";
import "source-map-support/register";
import http from "http";
import reload from "reload";
import expressStaticGzip from "express-static-gzip";

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(cors());
app.use("/build/public", expressStaticGzip('/build/public', {
    enableBrotli: true,
    orderPreference: ['br', 'gz'],
    setHeaders: function (res, path) {
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=31536000");
    }
}));
app.use(express.static("build/public"));

var server = http.createServer(app);
reload(app);
      acc.push(Promise.resolve(store.dispatch(route.component.initialData())));
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
   const currentRoute = routes.find(route => matchPath(req.url, route));
   const requestInitialData =
   currentRoute.component.initialData && currentRoute.component.initialData();
  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => {
      const context = {};
      const markup = renderToString(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
            <App />
          </StaticRouter>
        </Provider>
      );

      const initialData = store.getState();
      res.send(`
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <basehref="/">
            <title>Sample</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css.br">
          </head>

          <body>
            <div id="root">${markup}</div>
             <script src="client_bundle.js.br"></script>
             <script src="/reload/reload.js"></script>
            <script>window.__initialData__ = ${serialize(initialData)}</script>
          </body>
        </html>
      `);
    })
    .catch(next);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("App running,", PORT);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're compressing the client files in both Br and Gzip which looks correct as your app is serving them from `build/public`.

But the server-side-rendering, where its response is a HTML page, is not being compressed with either Brotli or Gzip by the looks of it. So the browser hits your server, it responds with an uncompressed HTML response and then downloads the Brotli compressed files before React does the hydration.